# Showing summations to be equal where the upper limit affects the argument.

Tags: summation, factorial

NOTE: I do not want the eventual answerer to post a full solution; I only wish that they point me in the right direction as to how to do so.

Ok I am trying to prove this for $n>3$:

$$2\left(\sum_{r=1}^{2^{n-2}} \frac{(2^n)!}{(2r-1)!(2^n-(2r-1))!}\right) = 2 \left( \sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-2}-1} \frac{(2^n)!}{(2r)!(2^n-2r)!}\right)+\frac{(2^n)!}{((2^{n-1})!)^2}$$

For reference, it is also my theory that the sum of either side is $$2^{2^{n}-1}$$

The LHS has now been shown to be equal to the theorised sum. Many thanks to Richard for the detailed explanation (please see his answer for reference). I have since attempted to solve the RHS with his methods. Unfortunately, upon following his steps, midway through
my efforts I was confronted by:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-2}-1} \binom{2^{n}-1}{2r-1}$$ - of which the notable problem is that for $r=0$ we get $$\binom{2^{n}-1}{-1}$$ which therefore leads to an obvious math error. 
Have I made an error here? If so can you point me in the right direction, or offer any relevant identities to show this?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks

EDIT: RESOLVED. I figured out how to work round it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe that

$$\sum_{r=1}^{2^{n-2}}{\frac{2^n!}{(2r-1)!(2^n-(2r-1))!}} = \sum_{r=1}^{2^{n-2}}{\binom{2^n}{2r-1}}.$$

We then use the identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$:

$$\sum_{r=1}^{2^{n-2}}{\binom{2^n}{2r-1}} = \sum_{r=1}^{2^{n-2}}{\binom{2^n-1}{2r-2}} + \sum_{r=1}^{2^{n-2}}{\binom{2^n-1}{2r-1}} $$
$$= \sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}{\binom{2^n-1}{r}} $$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(  \sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}{\binom{2^n-1}{r}} +  \sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}{\binom{2^n-1}{r}}\right) $$

Using the identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$, we can rewrite this as

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(  \sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}{\binom{2^n-1}{r}} +  \sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}{\binom{2^n-1}{2^n-1-r}}\right) $$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\left(  \sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}{\binom{2^n-1}{r}} +  \sum_{r=2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}-1}{\binom{2^n-1}{r}}\right) $$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=0}^{2^{n}-1}{\binom{2^n-1}{r}} = 2^{2^n-2}$$

where the final step follows from the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}}=2^n$. The RHS can be addressed similarly.

Comment: Hi Richard. Many thanks for this.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Mathematics.SE. If you feel that this answer or any future answers solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keeps the focus on older questions that still don't have answers.

Comment: Where did you get the penultimate sum from? I'm not certain how you made that jump. (The one with \binom{{2^n}-1}{r})

Comment: The first sum provides the the terms with $r$ even, while the second sum provides the terms with $r$ odd. For instance, for $n=3$, the first sum gives us $\binom{7}{0} + \binom{7}{2}$, while the second sum gives us $\binom{7}{1} + \binom{7}{3}$. The step you mentioned simply combines these two sums into one - in this case, we would have $\binom{7}{0} + \binom{7}{1} + \binom{7}{2} + \binom{7}{3}$.

Comment: Did you take into account in your edit the mistake I made (shown in the question)? If so, how exactly did that alter your answer?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you've inserted a factor of 2 to the RHS and one of the terms on the LHS, but the sums themselves haven't changed. If this is the case, the approach outlined in this answer should still hold.

Comment: Last question, how did you get the last sum? I don't understand how (although I'm sure there is good reason) you  took the 1/2 out and reduced the constraints - and how did you calculate that it is equal to the $${2^{2^{n}-1}}$$  Haven't done much work on factorials and combinatorics so my knowledge of the intricate rules is limited (I'd never seen the identity you gave, for example). This summation came from a square root algorithm I was investigating - obviously far away from this area!

Comment: I've edited the answer to flesh out some of those details, including the relevant combinatorial identities. I also realized that there was a mistake in my original answer; it was off by a factor of 2. That's fixed now.

Comment: Would you mind checking the other side? I ran into a problem... as shown in updated question